# How to get the subset of dataframe based on another dataframe in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just learnt pandas and basically I want to take the some rows of a dataframe based on the ids that are stored in another dataframe. Let me show you the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

f_data="data.tsv"
all_data = pd.read_csv(f_data,delimiter='\t',encoding='utf-8',header=None)
x_data = all_data[[0,1,3]]
y_data = all_data[[2]]

# Split train and test sets
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x_data,y_data,test_size=0.1)
```

all_data have 12 columns in total. I use 3 of the columns in x_data and 1 of them in y_data.

Once I create `x_train` and `x_test`, I would like to write these instances into `tsv` files but while doing that I want to write all of the 12 columns stored in `all_data`. To be able to do that, I need to match the instances in `x_train` and `x_test` with `all_data`. How could I do that ?

**EDIT**

Here how my data looks like:

`all_data`

```
        0                                                  1                              2    3   ...                                                8                      9     10    11
0       35  Auch in Großbritannien, wo 19 Atomreaktoren in...                       Ausstieg -1.0  ...                                      Sunday Times           Sunday Times   NaN     1
```

`# continues like that`

`x_train`

```
         0                                                  1    3
939   2074  Die CSU verlangt von der schwarz-gelben Koalit...  1.0
```

So, what I want to do is to get the rows starting with 939,710,288,854,433 in all_data and write them into a file.

Comment: Perhaps using `all_data.loc[x_data.index]`?  You haven't shown us your data though.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I edited my question by adding some data.

Comment: @JohnZwinck your edited comment works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `index` of the split data corresponds to the original, and can be used to look up the original data (assuming the index is unique):

```
all_data.loc[x_train.index]
all_data.loc[x_test.index]
```